# On firefox, how do I remove that pesky "Find" bar?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I use Vimperator, an extension that uses its own search method, so the Find bar becomes not only irrelevant but irritating! Is there a way to permanently prevent it from showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) to remove F3, C-g, C-f etc
2. Use Vimperators/Pentadactyl' own bindings to remove them. E.g. `:map -modes=n,v,c,i,t <F3> <Nop>`

Answer (score 0):

Not a Vimperator solution, but there is the Firefox Omnibar add-on that combines the Firefox search bar with the Address bar. You just type what you want in that bar, and somehow it works out what you want. Works fine with Vimperator.